# Problema con API al utilizar tipos génericos T

Tags: c#, api

Tengo una Web API en C#, donde uno de los métodos tiene esta firma:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GenerarExcel<T>([FromUri] GenerarExcelRequest<T> request)
```

Como dice el nombre del método, es para que cuando se envia un objeto de cualquier tipo, se genere un Excel con las propiedades como encabezados y los valores como las filas.

Probe que el verbo sea GET o POST y no funciona, ahora muestro el output que me da Postman.

En Postman enviando por el body un JSON de este estilo:

```
{
    "Nombre" : "Prueba",
    "Apellido" : "PruebaApellido",
    "FechaNacimiento" : "09/20/2019",
    "DNI" : 123456789
}
```

Me devuelve esta exepción:

```
 "Message": "An error has occurred.",
 "ExceptionMessage": "Cannot call action method 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage GenerarExcel[T](ApiR.Contracts.Excel.RequestResponses.GenerarExcelRequest`1[T])' on controller 'ApiR.Web.Controllers.ExcelController' because the action method is a generic method."
```

Estoy casi seguro que tiene que ser porque el método acepta valores de tipo genérico **T**, pero como empece hace poco con API no me doy cuenta como solucionarlo ya que ni siquiera entra a la primera línea del Controller.
Alguna sugerencia? Gracias!

Comment: Y T que tipos serian?

Comment: Dependeria del cliente que la use, porque es para generar reportes entonces puede ser por ejemplo un objeto cliente con valores string, o sobre un objeto Stock que tendria string e int. Creo que me quisiste preguntar eso

Comment: Las web api no pueden resolver genericos, no puedes usar T en un action de la webapi

Comment: Claro... estoy tratando de entender (porque nunca vi esto) como haria tu programa ya compilado, para en tiempo de ejecucion, adivinar cual es el tipo del json (que no es un objeto) que llega, y luego transformarlo a lo que vos queres, y luego procesarlo... suena.. raro.... se entiende? (no digo que no se pueda, no tengo idea, y seria interesante saber como se compilaria esto)

Comment: Ah.. yo pense que esto era mas normal. Ahora que lo pones de esa manera tambien me entraron dudas. Yo creia que podia detectar en tiempo de ejecucion si dentro de un JSON los valores eran string o int

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrias pasarle un object y luego desearlizar el json a object, si este lo puede parsear con AS, si comprobas que no es null seria tu objeto. Podrias incluir la logica en un Switch, el unboxing tiene un costo de proceso pero lo podes hacer, creo.

Comment: @RamiroBarone pero usar un objeto dinamico no causaria los mismos problemas que usar un objeto de tipo T?

Comment: En teoria no, porque todo hereda de object, y si usas T, segun lo que yo entiendo lo que hace el compilador es crearte una clase con ese T, en el momento que la llamas.

Comment: yo lo que haria seria en vez de tener algo generico , piensa, lo que necesita es un monton de strings, entonces enviar List<string> o IEnumerable<string> en vez de generico

Comment: @Iria si yo había pensado lo mismo y lo había puesto como una opción pero quieren que tratemos de saber el tipo de dato. Usando object ayer lo pude avanzar un poco así que si consigo finalizarlo subo la respuesta